# Extract components of strings and fill-down where missing in R

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to add the author portion to names based on the full name I received.

I got an example here

```
| SEQ | Species_name                                     |
|-----|--------------------------------------------------|
|1    | Aglaia lawii                                     |
|2    | Aglaia lawii                                     |
|2    | Aglaia lawii (Wight) C.J.Saldanha ex Ramamoorthy |
|3    | Alangium uniloculare                             |
|4    | Alangium uniloculare (Griff.) King               |
```

The result that I expect is that all species will have full resolution, including the author's name, as seen below.

```
| SEQ | Species_name                                    |
|---- |-------------------------------------------------|
|1    | Aglaia lawii (Wight) C.J.Saldanha ex Ramamoorthy|
|2    | Aglaia lawii (Wight) C.J.Saldanha ex Ramamoorthy|
|2    | Aglaia lawii (Wight) C.J.Saldanha ex Ramamoorthy|
|3    | Alangium uniloculare (Griff.) King              |
|4    | Alangium uniloculare (Griff.) King              |
```

So far, the way I can do is to change species names directly like this

```
df <- input %>% 
  mutate(Species_name = sub("Aglaia lawii", "Aglaia lawii (Wight) C.J.Saldanha ex Ramamoorthy", Species_name ))
```

but it looks so stupid when the plant list normally is very big with many names

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems a little under-defined. I think you're suggesting that we should see `"bc"` and, somehow calculating that it is closest to a longer string `"bc XX"`, it should be set to be the same, and similarly for the `"dc"` variants. Perhaps you can look into the `stringdist` package and, finding a clear way to be unambiguous, set shorter strings to their nearest long-string counterparts. (I have no idea what `col 1` is doing here, it seems a distractor. Correct me if I'm missing something.)

Comment: `col 1`  and `col 2`just is a name of the first column and second column, sorry for that.
Besides, let's say I am dealing with species name and some names are associated with author names, some names might be not. Now I'd want to add the author portion to the species name, which is now missing. Is that much better for you to understand it? 
`bc` is a species name and `XX` is a author part.

Comment: It might be better to frame this as *"extract components of strings and fill-down where missing"*. Is that a good interpretation? If so, if this goes into [tag:regex] or some form of string tokenization, it would be useful to have more representative sample data (unless there is always exactly one space).

Comment: thank you I will edit my post now

Comment: look at this as a "merge" problem and perform a "left_join()" with {dplyr}. Have a 2nd dataframe with the "shorter" Species name and a 2nd column with the "full name" (target name). Then join these by the shorter name (as the key) and remove the key column.

Comment: @Ray I tried it, but it didnt work for this case.

Comment: 1 solution I was thinking is I separate one name into 2,3 parts, like `Aglaia lawii` to `Aglaia` + `lawii` + `author name`, and I then will unite them again. However, since some author names are very long, so I cant do that.

Comment: Hi Duc, check my answer below. I tried to work with (dis)similarity of the strings. That is the only option I can think of, if there is no way to construct a proper key and look-up for the join.  If the names are well-formed, you may work with the separate approach by having something like firstname, familyname, rest. Again, this type of breaking requires that your names are well formed (otherwise, you always have to handle exceptions). While it is not a join, it follows the same idea/pattern. Complete a column based on a match. Somewhere we have to create a well-formed pattern to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments it appears that it is not feasible to construct a key for `joining` the `Species_name` with a `look-up` table.

What you could do is determine the "similarity" of your (species) names with such a look-up table. This assumes that your (species) names are different enough. To determine the "similarity" or better the "distance" of the strings (your names), we use the package `{stringdist}`.
There are many string-(dis)similarity algorithms. For the example below, I work on the basis that your (species) names begin in a similar way. (Note: you may have to ensure this or use another algorithm for the distance measure).

You did not provide a fully reproducible example. I construct an example input tibble based on your question and derive the look-up vector from this tibble. You may be able to extract the look-up from your data in another manner.

**prep work**

```
library(dplyr)                     # for data crunching
# install.packages("stringdist")   # install from CRAN
library(stringdist)                # use stringdist

# emulate example
input <- tibble::tribble(
   ~SEQ, ~Species_name
    , 1, "Aglaia lawii"
    , 2, "Aglaia lawii"
    , 2, "Aglaia lawii (Wight) C.J.Saldanha ex Ramamoorthy"
    , 3, "Alangium uniloculare"
    , 4, "Alangium uniloculare (Griff.) King"
   )

# create a look-up vector of all "full names"
lookup <- input %>% 
   filter(grepl(pattern = ".\\("    # checking for the opening bracket
                , x = Species_name)
   ) %>% 
   pull(Species_name)               # keep the names column as look-up vector
```

**string (dis)similarity**

There are many algorithm to determine the (dis)similarity of strings. The `{stringdist}` package offers some. There exists a function that provides a `distance`. Without going in too much details, think about distance being the number of operations required to turn a string into one of the lookup strings. For more details, read up in the documentation. The different algorithm consider different ways of doing these transformations (and many things more). The `Jaro-Winkler` algorithm gives a preference to strings that match from the beginning.

Let's check what the Jaro-Winkler `jw` (method) implementation in `{stringdist}` works:

```
stringdist(input$Species_name[1], lookup, method = "jw")
[1] 0.2500000 0.3908497
```

From this we can derive that the first element of our lookup is similar (lower distance) and starts similarly than `Aglaia lawii (Wight) C.J.Saldanha ex Ramamoorthy`.

**iterating over our tibble and replace/identify the best full names**

As we work with a tibble of species names, we need to compare the actual species names with the look-up vector. To iterate over the different rows we use `{purrr}` and apply the (dis)similarity comparison.
For the latter we construct a short function to make this more compact.

Note: The `lookup` was created above based on the example data. This might however come from elsewhere.

```
library(purrr)

best_guess_full_name <- function(.df, .options = lookup){
#----- best guess bg picks from options look-up the most similar (:= min dissimilar)
    bg <- .options[which.min(stringdist(.df$Species_name, .options, method = "jw"))]
#------ append the "best guess" to the row (dataframe) and return
    df <- .df %>% mutate(Full_species = bg)
}
```

Let's test the function taking the 2nd row of input (i.e. input[2, ]).
Note: the brackets around the call will print the result, since we do not use return in our function.

```
( input[2,] %>% best_guess_full_name() )
# A tibble: 1 x 3
    SEQ Species_name Full_species                                    
  <dbl> <chr>        <chr>                                           
1     2 Aglaia lawii Aglaia lawii (Wight) C.J.Saldanha ex Ramamoorthy
```

**putting it all together**

With this we can now process (iterate over each row) the input dataframe/tibble and return in as a dataframe/tibble.

```
input %>% 
   split(row.names(authors)) %>%              # creates a list, each row a data frame
   purrr::map_dfr(.f = best_guess_full_name)  # iterate over every list element (row dataframe)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
    SEQ Species_name                                     Full_species                                    
  <dbl> <chr>                                            <chr>                                           
1     1 Aglaia lawii                                     Aglaia lawii (Wight) C.J.Saldanha ex Ramamoorthy
2     2 Aglaia lawii                                     Aglaia lawii (Wight) C.J.Saldanha ex Ramamoorthy
3     2 Aglaia lawii (Wight) C.J.Saldanha ex Ramamoorthy Aglaia lawii (Wight) C.J.Saldanha ex Ramamoorthy
4     3 Alangium uniloculare                             Alangium uniloculare (Griff.) King              
5     4 Alangium uniloculare (Griff.) King               Alangium uniloculare (Griff.) King
```

This does what - I think you can do - if the `left_join()` approach and proper keys do not work. The drawback of this solution is that we "estimate" the full names.

- Thus, if the functions from `{stringdist}` do not help to get this right, you would need to specify your own "similarity" measurement.
- The result might be - mathematically - wrong as (dis)similarity results in equal distance for a certain combination of the wrong full name. You may need to break ties, etc.

Hope this gets you going!

Comment: Hi @Ray thank you so much for this. I will check it out. This morning, I was doing like to create a vector of full species name, then I use `lapply` function to match every element with every row. It worked fine. However, for some species identified to genus level, the code will randomly match them with names that we dont know. I am thinking to exclude `OUT` species first, then do it again. Here are my code, what do you think?

Comment: `name <- data.frame(c())`  #only 1 column
`colnames(name) <- "full_name"`

`df <- input_table %>%
  mutate(name = lapply(Species_name, function(x){name %>% filter(grepl(x, full_name))})) %>% unnest(tree_name)`

Comment: Awesome. Good to see that you found another way to "grab" the names and match them. Looks good. `lapply()` is not bad either. I tend to use the `tidyverse` - do not get hung up by this. Your approach is sound!

Comment: I am also trying to get used to play with `tidyverse`. Seems to be I have to learn alot. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Ray, I just tried to use your code. However, I could not use your created function , it said that `full_name` can not be found. Can you take a look at it one more time since I might have to use both ways (inlucde my way) to get the exact unique name. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Duc, mea culpa. `full_name` is the vector with "all" the "full names" ... I created it based on your example data and called it `lookup`. Changed the code accordingly. It is a parameter in the function (aka ... .option=<<provide-look-up-of-all-full-names>> set as a default. You can replace it with whatever vector-name you assign. Sorry for not being clearer. Please note, that you might get the "full names" from somewhere else (and my derivation is a simplification), but the function will work for any given vector with the respective names.