# Get the latest updated value in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to make another question following this ([Get the latest updated value based on other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69438483/get-the-latest-updated-value-based-on-other-columns/69439619?noredirect=1#comment122737446_69439619)) since my question might not be clear.

Initially, I have 2 dataframes in which one contains NA value in column `name2`, and the other contains `NA` value in column `name1`. Then, I used `bind_rows` to get one big dataframe as example here. The column `name3` is the combination of `name1` and `name2`.

```
name1               name2                  name3
Acer laurinum        NA                     Acer laurinum
Acmella paniculata   NA                     Acmella paniculata
Aglaia lawii         NA                     Aglaia lawii
............         NA                     ...................
NA                   Acer laurinum Hassk.   Acer laurinum Hassk.
NA                   Aglaia lawii (Wight)   Aglaia lawii (Wight)
NA                   ....................   ....................
```

As you can see, several names in column `name3` missing the author part. That why I would like to update those names based on either the column `name2` or `name3`.
Any suggesstion for me using `tidyverse`?

Code for example

```
df <- data.frame(
name1 = c("Acer laurinum", "Acmella paniculata", "Aglaia lawii", NA, NA), 
name2 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Acer laurinum Hassk.", "Aglaia lawii (Wight)"),
name3 = c("Acer laurinum", "Acmella paniculata", "Aglaia lawii", "Acer laurinum Hassk.", "Aglaia lawii (Wight)"))
```

My desired output

```
name1               name2                  name3
Acer laurinum        NA                     Acer laurinum Hassk.
Acmella paniculata   NA                     Acmella paniculata
Aglaia lawii         NA                     Aglaia lawii (Wight)
NA                   Acer laurinum Hassk.   Acer laurinum Hassk.
NA                   Aglaia lawii (Wight)   Aglaia lawii (Wight)
```

Comment: Ok, I think i had a confusion with your expected.  I thought `name3` was not present in the data

Comment: oh, i see. I did create a vector of good name before and then I used `lapply` to bind the author name, like this post. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68637196/extract-components-of-strings-and-fill-down-where-missing-in-r). However, some cases when I matched going wrong, then I think that might be not a good option

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:
The idea:

1. bring data in long format
2. create a `helper` column with the first word of the names using `word` from `stringr`
3. group by `helper` and `mutate` value with the last of the group
4. bring back to wide format

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -id
  ) %>% 
  mutate(helper= word(value, 1)) %>% 
  group_by(helper) %>% 
  mutate(value= last(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name,
    values_from = value
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-id, -helper) %>% 
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ !is.na(.)))
```

```
  name1                name2                name3               
  <chr>                <chr>                <chr>               
1 Acer laurinum Hassk. NA                   Acer laurinum Hassk.
2 Acmella paniculata   NA                   Acmella paniculata  
3 Aglaia lawii (Wight) NA                   Aglaia lawii (Wight)
4 NA                   Acer laurinum Hassk. Acer laurinum Hassk.
5 NA                   Aglaia lawii (Wight) Aglaia lawii (Wight)
```

Comment: thank you so much. It worked well here. However, something weird happened when I ran for my data. The row was not the same anymore, it was increased by some reasons. For example, several unique row with good solution for `name1`  and `name3` splited to 2 different rows

Comment: Maybe you could create this as a new question. It seems worth to handle it!

Comment: thank you. Problem happend when we created the `value` column, some how the `id` matching wrong name. I will create a new topic